# Android Mahjong score counting app

Tags: android

I'm looking for an Mahjong counting app that lets me:

- set player names
- input the score for each player
- indicate who scored Mahjong

The app will

- calculate totals for each of the 4 players
- keep track of the current wind (who's East, what is the wind of the round).

So, e.g.:

- Wind of the round is South
- Pete had East, Pete scored Mahjong
- Pete had 128 points, the other three players X,Y,Z had 20,40,60 respectively

The app will:

- Calculate that X,Y,Z all pay 256 points to Pete
- Calculate that X receives 20 from Y and Z, Y receives 40 from X and Z, Z receives 60 from X an Y
- Add the result for this round (Pete +768, X -316, Y -256, Z -196) to the totals
- Indicate that Pete **remains east**, there will now be at least 5 games with wind of the round being South

I have looked at several free apps from which Kurt Van den Branden's [Mahjong Counter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=be.teige.android.MahjongCounter&hl=en) meets all those requirements **but** it requires me to enter all the pungs, kongs etc. that each player made. That is far too much data entry, it is much faster to count this mentally. We can add the scores for the stones and do some doubling ourselves, we just need to be able to enter each players' score.

If the program works as indicated, I'm perfectly happy to pay for it.

There is a paid [Mahjong Helper & Calculator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mahjonghelper.android&hl=en) from Cyberdog Software ([website here](http://www.mahjonghelper.com/)), which seems to meet most criteria (notably not having to input all tiles), so I would appreciate input from anyone knowing this app. I'm confused about it rounding up scores, and unsure if it properly tracks the winds.

*Note* I'm not sure which variant we are playing (that's why I added a scoring example). It could be 'European Classical' since I'm in The Netherlands.

[Edited to add]
We currently use the Excel spreadsheet [Mahjong calculator v2.xls](http://www.jandoggen.org/uploads/Mahjong%20calculator%20v2.xls), from which I do not know the author. It does exactly what we require, but it's not good to use on a smartphone.

Comment: The spreadsheet was exactly what I was looking for, and converts happily to a Google online spreadsheet as well so a group of people can share it.  (e.g. if they are playing mahjong online at a site like https://mahjongtime.com/ but want to ignore that site's scoring system and use their own)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have purchased the [**Mahjong Helper & Calculator**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mahjonghelper.android&hl=en) that I mentioned in my question, and it does what I want. I can just add the score and it will calculate scores, winds, who's East etc. I tested it using the European rules and found no errors.

If you want to, you can enter each persons' combinations and let the program calculate the score, *with* an explanation. Nice for beginning players maybe, but as I wrote in my question, to much work for me. The interface to enter the combinations is fine (I would not know a faster way).

<strike>The only drawbacks I found with the program is that it does not change orientation with the phone, and that it seemed to respond a bit sluggish. I also have the impression that it draws a lot of power, I could not leave it on for an entire afternoon without plugging my Android phone into a power outlet.</strike><sup>*</sup>

All in all, I'm happy with the program, it's worth purchasing.

[Added: The concern I mentioned about rounding scores is unnecessary - it is an *option* you can enable or disable]

<sup>* I no longer have an issue with the non-rotation; the power+sluggishness issue has been fixed in an update. The author reacted quickly in the (one) email correspondence I had with him.</sup>